# How to get the response content when server error

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I wish I could get the response content when the server returns an error with code 5XX or 4XX.

Here is my configuration :

API Rest (Laravel) :

```
public function login(Request $request) {
$this->validateLogin($request);
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
    $user = $this->guard()->user();
    $user->generateToken();
    return response()->json($user, 200);
}
return response()->json('Login or password unknown', 401);
```

}

Angular service :

```
public getUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post(this.employeeAPI + 
  'login', JSON.stringify(user), { headers: this.headers });
}
```

Angular component :

```
public login(): void {
  this.loginService.getUser(this.user).subscribe(
    (user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    },
    (error) => {
    // Is it possible to get the content of response ?

    }
  );
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: for a start you could console.log(error) an see for yourself if the data you want is in that object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look at the response with a higher point of view, you have to observe the response like this:

```
 return this.httpClient.post(this.employeeAPI
     + 'login', JSON.stringify(user), { headers: this.headers, observe: 'response' });
```

The response will be of type [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse). That implies you extract the `body` yourself from the response, but that also allows you to retrieve the status code.

Comment: just passing through, may i inquire if that is because the $http.post promise returned by angular is rejected when the status code of the request's response is 30x,40x or 50x, right? unless you pass `observe: 'response'`  as part the request's configuration, so that allows to have a code flow in the `then` block instead of the `catch`?...mmmm

Comment: @Victor exactly, by doing this, the requests with a status code outside of the `200-299` range will fire a normal event, it's up to the developer to check the `response.ok` property and react accordingly. Source: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponseBase#ok

Comment: nice! thanks for sharing... this could help anyone writing javascript (angularjs) web clients for http-rest-based-api applications

Comment: Indeed, this is very close to the native `Response` object implemented in browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't know how to accept an answer, but now I understood how to do it and it is done ! Best regards